# Vue - where should I declare element variable to use in any lifecycle or method?

Tags: vue.js, async-await, scope

I'm new to Vue and wondering where I would declare something like:

```
const qualityDropdown = document.getElementById("qualityDropdown");
```

in a single place so I can use it in any lifecycle and / or method in a component without having to re-declare it in every place. Part of the issue being that sometimes elements are created after an axios call and aren't immediately present.

Would this go in `data(){return{}}` or `computed(){}`?

Comment: It really depends on the situation. Would you mind clarifying your question? Is this to boost performance? Or is it to keep the code DRY? How are the elements being created? Might need to see that code, if you're doing manual dom manipulation or just adding elements with `v-if="dataLoaded"`, that would change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define its `ref` as follows:

```
<select ref="myDropDown" id="qualityDropdown"></select>
```

And call it using

```
this.$refs.myDropDown
```

Comment: Thank you kindly sir!

Comment: Just be aware that they (the refs) will be `undefined` until added to the dom. https://codepen.io/AlgeoMA/pen/ExjdYGV?editors=1010

Comment: Well, it is made to be used from mounted and forward

Comment: See codepen for what I mean. Sometimes elements don't appear in the DOM even after mounted (like if removed via v-if)